# GIF image does not loop in HTML

Tags: html, loops, gif

I'm trying to put a gif ([this one](http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mclsum7WN01r8p5cro1_500.gif)) to my webpage,
however, it only makes one turn and stops.

I put it like this: (I put it directly to the HTML source code)

```
<img src='http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mclsum7WN01r8p5cro1_500.gif'></img>
```

However, the strange thing is, I was inserting it dynamically with JavaScript, with no problem. I was doing something like this:

```
<script>
$( "#my_button" ).click(function(){
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "<a>Please wait, loading...</a><img src='http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mclsum7WN01r8p5cro1_500.gif'></img>";       
});
</script>
```

Or maybe the loading process was so short that it was disappearing before one turn.

But anyways, the original gif is looping infinitely as you see. So why it doesn't in my page?

Thanks !

**p.s.:** I styled the image with css. I wrapped it in a div, so that the unnecessary white parts are outside the div. May be related.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: And when you say you were "putting it with no problem earlier, with Javascript" does that mean the JS isn't working, or it doesn't work in plain HTML either now?

Comment: This is browser behavior which don't play animated gif (by desing or optionally). For example, in Opera it's F12 menu, "Enable animated images"

Comment: @autibyte Chrome. And I mean I was inserting it dynamically with JavaScript earlier, now I put it directly to the HTML code. And I will set .css('visibility','hidden') when the loading is finished.